# Autoclean postgresql data when stop maven

Tags: postgresql, maven, intellij-idea

I've been writing integration tests for a few weeks, the data from the database was only received when I start maven in intellij and this helped me a lot because every time I stopped maven the data was cleared, but when I decided to press maven install then validate because the program had new functionalities and the database is no longer cleared. How can I set it again so that every time the database is cleared after stopping maven in intellij?

Comment: The integration test should start with ensuring that the database is in a known state. How do you do this now?

Comment: The database generates default data from the program when I started maven, but now the data is not being cleared and since I am also doing post requests this is causing me problems.

Comment: Add the cleanup code to the default data generation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You provide very little information. If somebody assigned you this task, ask for assistance.